# Is there any guaranteed interaction between non-parallel lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

It is my understanding that non-parallel lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ will always intersect eventually. Is there any sort of guaranteed interaction between lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or is it possible for two lines to operate without any knowledge of each other?

My thought on this is that similar to how two points can exist without interaction in $\mathbb{R}^2$, two lines can exist without interaction in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and that it is non-parallel planes that are guaranteed to intersect in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Which leads me to generalize that non-parallel (not sure if parallel applies above $\mathbb{R}^3$) hyperplanes will always interact in their ambient space.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SkewLines.html
See here.

Comment: "is it possible for two lines to operate without any knowledge of each other?" Of course. They're lines, they don't know anything. :)

Comment: Also, with regard to the hyperplanes, I am certain you are correct, but I don't have a proof of such.

Comment: @avid19 as a line's rights activist I am appalled!

Comment: Imagine a line extending north to south indefinitely, along the z axis. Now one unit west, on the x axis, imagine a line extending perpendicular to that first line. No intersection. Lines do not have to intersect in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in $\Bbb{R}^3$, you can consider the lines $(0,0,t)$ and $(1,t,0)$. These two obviously never intersect and aren't parallel.

In $\Bbb{R}^n$ we may consider the "$n-2$ dimensional"  subsets $(0,0,t_1,\dots, t_{n-2})$ and $(1,t_1,t_2,\dots, t_{n-2},0)$. These are not parallel (meaning their difference is not constant) but never intersect.

However if you have "$n-1$ dimensional" subsets, they will either intersect somewhere or be parallel (and non equal). This is a standard result from linear algebra.